# Seat Cordoba 6K2 (2000.) Not work central trunk locking, manual works

Tags: electrical, key, seat, central-locking, trunk

I have a problem with central locking trunk on Seat Cordoba 2000. year model with Signo packet of equipment. Manual locking is working.
I have try locking motor connect to 12V source, an it works. Locking switch also work.
When I measure Voltage on motor connector, I got 0.02V or - 0.02V.
I test all fuses, and no one are bad.

Problem is probably somewhere in wireing.
I have buy a "Seat Cordoba PDF Workshop Service & Repair Manual 1996-2002 Instant Download" from Easymanuals.co.uk but there is no wiring schema for central locking.

Anyone have the solution?
Thank you.

Comment: After I replaced wires, everythink work fine.